# Why some Android apps can only be updated via WIFI network?

Tags: android, smartphone

This is not a programming question, so maybe Stack Overflow is not the best place to ask it, so feel free to redirect me on the most suited Q/A site but anyway.

I have some apps on my Android phone, which can't work when I am outside without WIFI connection. When I use data connection for my phone, some apps like Google maps are functionnal but some others (like Yuka, or AlloCine), don't answer at all.

It's like if an communication with some server is KO (and no timeout) so the app splashscreen never ends.

When I go to the preferences of the app, I see that the data use is not disabled, so for me nothing is supposed to prevent the use of data for it...

Do you have met a problem like that?
Do you have an idea of the reasons?

Comment: GPS isnt really data.... how do you think the old style GPS systems work without data? Same concept. GPS hit devices through satellite....there's a difference. When you call 911, they can find you with the GPS of your device... assuming location services are on.

Comment: Ok but Google maps was an example. I can use other apps without geolocation, like Gmail or a simple browser.

Comment: u cant GET mail within internet.... but when mail is loaded, sure, thats fine.

Comment: Some other apps are working and don't use any cached data.
I can do a internet research on internet with random keyword and it's working.